# How do I tell Gradle that a strangely-numbered dependency version is a newer version?

Tags: gradle

Our project uses Gradle and we have an internal dependency with a somewhat unusual versioning convention. We have releases like 1.0, 1.1, etc, but bleeding edge changes are in a version called `dev`. This is causing trouble with version conflicts where the numbered versions are evicting the `dev` version (it would appear letters are considered "older" than numbers). Thus our build doesn't have the latest changes.

Basically, we want it to be that `dev`always wins over the numbered versions. We are aware that we could do `force = true`, but we don't want to do that because when we are back to the stable, numbered versions, we don't want to force an older version.

The structure is as follows:

```
- Project
   // We want to use this bleeding-edge version, but it's being evicted
   - Dependency: dev
   - OtherDependency: 1.0
       // We are pulling in the last stable version transitively
       - Dependency: 1.1
```

Is there any way to tell Gradle that `dev` > any numbered version, and keep the standard version number ordering for the rest? Thus `1.0 < 1.1 < dev`?

If it matters, we are using Ivy for our dependency management.

Comment: Interesting case. Could you please prepare an SSCCE since I can't reproduce it? As far as I understood you do remove `dev` version while subsequent stable version is released?

Comment: It seems that I've prepared a demo but with maven. It works in the following way. Dependency with version `1.+` is declared and three versions are installed `1.0`, `1.1` and `dev`. If `dev` is specified as `release` in `maven-metadata.xml` it's resolved regardless of the dependency `1.+` that is defined.

Comment: @Opal Yes, we do remove dev when a subsequent stable version is released, although we don't always get around to it immediately. What sort of SSCCE are you looking for? A snippet from a build.gradle file?

Comment: Here you can find a demo: https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/42960801. Enter `lib` change `version` to `1.0`, `1.1` and `dev` running `gradle build install` after every change. Then navigate to `project`. If `dev` is not the latest version `1.+` should be resolved, otherwise `dev` should be resolved. Use `printDeps` task to verify. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Opal Thanks for that. I'm going to need to install Maven in order to try out your code. To be clear, are you saying that you've found a fix? Or just that you've reproduced the problem?

Comment: No need to install anything, just try out the demo. Hope it's a fix 

Comment: Have you checked my demo?